# Binding To ItemView the change Events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I would like to re-render a list made using `Marionette.ItemView`
when the corresponding model in `ItemView` change.

Any idea about the best way to active this task?

```
// Collection passed to Marionette.CompositeView
myCollection.attributes = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'bar'
        closed: false
    },
    ….
];
```

---

```
// Marionette.ItemView
myModel.set({
    closed: true
}); // when this model change I would like to re-render the copositeView 
    // or remove the Marionette.ItemView
```

---

P.S:
If I try the following code(1) in `Marionette.ItemView`,
when I save the model, I get the following error(2).

(1)

```
// Marionette.ItemView
initialize: function () {
    this.model.on('change', this.render);
}
```

(2)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'serializeData'
```

Comment: I havent worked with Marionette but you will need to bind to the models change events in the view, so that the view understands to re-render itself.

Comment: I did try to make it in Marionette.ItemView but I get the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'serializeData'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is a good practice to use the _.bindAll in your initialize method. May be your issue is related to the scope.

```
initialize: function () {
    _.bindAll(this);
    this.model.on('change', this.render);
}
```

If bindAll does not fix your issue please paste your Model and View.

Comment: thanks, your code fix the problem about the Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object]. But the list is not update. I need to refresh the page. anyway I will make another question.

Comment: I did post another question about this: [Events between Marionette.CompositeView and Marionette.ItemView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312846/events-between-marionette-compositeview-and-marionette-itemview)

Comment: Using Marionette `bindTo` allows Marionette to stop the binding when the view is closed. It's definitely the way to go.

Comment: answer where using 'modelEvents' propperty on the Marionette.View and thus Marionette.ItemView is more appropriate to be accepted as correct answer.

See: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md#modelevents-and-collectionevents

Answer (score 17):

Marionette provides a `modelEvents` property that takes care of the proper binding to the model events.

In your *ItemView* simply add the following to universally have the ItemView update when the model changes:

```
'modelEvents': {
    'change': 'render'
},
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 6):

For event binding and unbinding to work automagically in Marionette, you should use the view's `bindTo` method. For instance:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.bindTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
}
```

Also `bindTo` sets the context correctly, so you don't need `_.bindAll()` with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable this behaviour by default in ItemView changing its prototype:

```
Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.prototype["modelEvents"] = { "change" : "render"};
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this something like what you were trying to do?

```
MyItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    modelEvents: {
        "change:closed": "render"
    }
});

MyCompositeView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    itemView: MyItemView
});

MyApp.addRegions({main_region: "#main"});

MyApp.main_region.show(new MyCompositeView({collection: new MyCollection()});
```

By default, Marionette.ItemView has a serializeData function that just return the result of calling toJSON on the this.model. Of course you can override this function by defining your own serializeData on your ItemView extension just like when extending any other javascript object. HTH