# Events between Marionette.CompositeView and Marionette.ItemView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have two modules `itemView.js` and `ListView.js`.
Everything works when I fetch the data.

The problem is about the `item view` (1) when I change the corresponding model.

a) the `ListView.js` (2) displays all the object which models have `closed` value equal to `false` (3)

b) the action `closeTask` in (1) changes the value of the model
from `closed: false` to `closed: true`

c) when b) occurs nothing change,
 but if I reload the page I get the right results (the model having the `closed` value equal to `true` is not displayed).

How should I fix this issue?

---

(1)

```
// itemView.js
var itemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    },

    events: {
        'click #close': 'closeTask'
    },

    template: itemTemplate,

    tagName: 'li',

    closeTask: function () {
        if (!this.model.get('closed')) {
            this.model.save({
                closed: true
            });
        }
    }

});
```

---

(2)

```
// ListView.js
var ListView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

    template: listTemplate,

    itemView: itemView

});
```

---

(3)

```
// Collection
myCollection.attributes = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'bar'
        closed: false
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'bar2'
        closed: false
    },
    ….
];
```

---

P.S.:

When I fetch the collection, the server give me just the models which have the closed attribute equal to false.

```
app.addInitializer(function () {
    myCollection = new MyCollection();
    myCollection.fetch();
});
```

Comment: what do you expect this to do? what change do you expect to see when the item is closed?

Answer (score 1):

I did not work with Marionette but I have been working with Backbone, my thought is that Marionette is not refreshing the template or something like it.

What happens if you try this?

```
// itemView.js
var itemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    },

    onRender : function(){
       //verify your model:
       console.log( this.model.toJSON() );
       if (this.model.get('closed')) {
          this.$el.fadeOut();//bye bye item
       }
    },

    events: {
        'click #close': 'closeTask'
    },

    template: itemTemplate,

    tagName: 'li',

    closeTask: function () {
        if (!this.model.get('closed')) {
            this.model.save({
                closed: true
            });
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: I updated my code to use onRender as Marionnet has one method for it. https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md

Comment: +1 yes your code works. Anyway Marionette should re-render this change automatically or maybe I missed something.

Comment: Probably you are missing something, paste me please the code where you decide to show or not the item depending the value of closed.

Comment: When I fetch the collection, the server give me just the models which have the `closed attribute equal to false`.

Comment: That is the reason because render did not hide anything if you did not have a logic on the FrontEnd to hide it. So I think that my answer was the solution that you needed. Now you have your BackEnd validation and "on demand" validation at the FrontEnd.